# TCN model result seems like offset by one time step

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, data-science, overfitting-underfitting

I have been training a temperature dataset with TCN model. I Have tested it on small data available. I am training a bivariate TCN model with the data which I am giving input is Maximum temperature and minimum temperature to predict maximum temperature.  I want to know if this is overfitting or if the graph is right [Graph here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Amv50.png)

Below is my model

```
i = Input(shape=(lookback_window, 2))
m = TCN(nb_filters = 64)(i)
m = Dense(3, activation='linear')(m)

model = Model(inputs=[i], outputs=[m])
model.summary()
```

The summary of the model is [given here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hxq0D.png)

Answer (score 0):

evaluate accuracy during epochs:

```
acc = sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have edited and added more details